# How to make a picture align on the left side using Bootstraps Grid

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I cant find the error to make my picture on the left side of the cards, im still learning on using bootstrap

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="stat-widget-one">
                        <div class="stat-content dib">
                            <div class="stat-text">Course Enrolled</div>
                            <div class="stat-digit"><?php //echo(!empty($totalCustomers))
number_format($totalCustomers,0,'',','):'0';?>0</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="stat-widget-one">
                        <div class="stat-content dib">
                            <div class="stat-text">Course In Progress</div>
                            <div class="stat-digit"><?php //echo(!empty($totalDocumentsLess7Years))?number_format($totalDocumentsLess7Years,0,'',','):'0';?>0</div>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="w-100 d-none d-md-block"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="stat-widget-one">
                        <div class="stat-content dib">
                            <div class="stat-text">Course Completed</div>
                            <div class="stat-digit"><?php //echo(!empty($totalDocumentsMore7Years))?number_format($totalDocumentsMore7Years,0,'',','):'0';?>0</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="stat-widget-one">
                        <div class="stat-content dib">
                            <div class="stat-text">Certificates</div>
                            <div class="stat-digit"><?php //echo(!empty($totalArchive))?number_format($totalArchive,0,'',','):'0';?>0</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" class="trainees">
            <img
src="https://www.thesprucepets.com/thmb/APYdMl_MTqwODmH4dDqaY5q0UoE=/750x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc():format(webp)/all-about-tabby-cats-552489-hero-a23a9118af8c477b914a0a1570d4f787.jpg" alt="trainees" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
</div>
```

Do i need to alter the columns? I've already tried on the same row but still not working. Here are my current view [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DO4LO.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

just add another div of **class row** after the cards and place the image section inside it to position it to the left.

Here is the working code

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="stat-widget-one">
                        <div class="stat-content dib">
                            <div class="stat-text">Course Enrolled</div>
                            <div class="stat-digit"><?php //echo(!empty($totalCustomers))
number_format($totalCustomers,0,'',','):'0';?>0</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="stat-widget-one">
                        <div class="stat-content dib">
                            <div class="stat-text">Course In Progress</div>
                            <div class="stat-digit"><?php //echo(!empty($totalDocumentsLess7Years))?number_format($totalDocumentsLess7Years,0,'',','):'0';?>0</div>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="w-100 d-none d-md-block"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="stat-widget-one">
                        <div class="stat-content dib">
                            <div class="stat-text">Course Completed</div>
                            <div class="stat-digit"><?php //echo(!empty($totalDocumentsMore7Years))?number_format($totalDocumentsMore7Years,0,'',','):'0';?>0</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="stat-widget-one">
                        <div class="stat-content dib">
                            <div class="stat-text">Certificates</div>
                            <div class="stat-digit"><?php //echo(!empty($totalArchive))?number_format($totalArchive,0,'',','):'0';?>0</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3" class="trainees">
            <img 
src="https://www.thesprucepets.com/thmb/APYdMl_MTqwODmH4dDqaY5q0UoE=/750x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc():format(webp)/all-about-tabby-cats-552489-hero-a23a9118af8c477b914a0a1570d4f787.jpg" alt="trainees" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
  </div>  
       
  
</div>
```

Output looks like this. Hope this solves

[image]